# Como es que la recursividad realmente funciona?

Tags: c, recursión

-Tengo una duda con respecto a la recursion, la establecere a partir de la sucesion de fibonacci con un codigo en C...

```
int fibonacci(int numero)
{
    if (numero == 1 || numero ==0)
    {
       return 1;
    }
    else
    {
       return fibonacci(numero-1)+fibonacci(numero-2);
    }
}
```

-Para poder darme a entender, tendre que ir paso a paso imitando a la CPU partiendo de que por ejemplo quiero el fibonacci de 5...

```
printf("El numero perteneciente a la posicion 5 en la sucecion de fibonacci es %i",fibonacci(5));
```

-En este caso la CPU diria algo asi...

```
'Bueno como 5 no es ni 0 ni es 1 entonces voy a retornar el 
 fibonaci de fibonacci(5-1)+fibonacci(5-2)....(una vez que 
 llega al fibonacci de 1) bueno ya que el numero que me piden es 1  retornare 1'
```

-Aqui es donde esta mi duda, una vez que se llega al caso borde, como es que la CPU recuerda que tiene que sumar ese mismo resultado con el otros numeros que antes no conocia. Entiendo perfectamente el concepto de recursion, se como funciona, el punto esta en... ¿Como hace la maquina para entenderlo?.

-Esta claro que las llamadas a la funcion se almacenan en algun sitio de la PC como 'tareas por hacer o algo por el estilo', ¿cual es ese lugar?

-PD: se que me faltan muchos acentos, tengo el teclado en ingles y no se donde se pone la tilde (:-|

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Alguien puede explicarme la recursividad en C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175189/alguien-puede-explicarme-la-recursividad-en-c)

Comment: Has manualmente lo que haria el `inline` en tu funcion, y creo que lo entenderas mejor,.

Comment: Creo que estás preguntando sobre lo que viene siendo [la pila de la CPU](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registro_de_pila). Por ese enlace puedes empezar.

Comment: @Trauma Si, es exactamente lo que buscaba, si puedes establecerlo como una respuesta, te daria el check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Los programas de computadora tienen una región de memoria llamada comúnmente la [pila de llamadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_de_llamadas) ([call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) en inglés), o simplemente **stack**, que es utilizada, entre otras cosas, para almacenar la dirección de retorno cada vez que se llama una función, además del valor de variables locales, parámetros, etc.

OJO, que este mecanismo no existe solo para el caso de llamadas recursivas, sino para toda llamada a una función.

Se llama pila, porque es administrada como eso, una [pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_(inform%C3%A1tica)) (LIFO).

Siempre que se llama a una rutina o función, se crea un nuevo *marco de pila* en la pila y dentro de este se almacena la dirección de ejecución a donde debe retornar el programa, variables locales, etc. Imagina este código:

```
{
  var1 = funcion_a(param1, param2);
  var2 = funcion_b(param3, param4);
  var3 = var1 + var2;
}
```

Cuando se está ejecutando y se llama a `funcion_a`, la ejecución salta a la primera línea del código de dicha función (en realidad es un poco más complejo, pero mantengamos la idea simple), y cuando esa función termina, ¿cómo sabe el programa cuál es la siguiente instrucción que debe ejecutar? La `funcion_a` puede llamarse desde muchos distontos lugares del programa (imagina la cantidad de llamadas a funciones como `printf` en un programa C de consola). Entonces, acude a la pila, donde tiene almacenada la dirección de retorno y *salta* la ejecución a este punto para ejecutar dicha instrucción, que en nuestro ejemplo sería asignar el valor de retorno a la variable `var1`, para luego llamar a `funcion_b`.

Es esa misma estructura la que es utilizada cuando se hacen llamadas recursivas. El programa no tiene *nada especial* para manejar una llamada recursiva, y el compilador ignora por completo el hecho de que la llamada a `fibonacci` está ocurriendo desde dentro de `fibonacci`.

Cuando el programa se está ejecutando y se encuentra una llamada a `fibonacci`, se crea un nuevo *marco de pila* (stack frame), donde se almacena la dirección de retorno (y otras yerbas) y se transfiere el control a la primera línea de `fibonacci`. Cuando esta función retorna, continua con la siguiente instrucción.

Cuando, dentro de la función escribes este código:

```
return fibonacci(numero-1)+fibonacci(numero-2);
```

Esto se traduce en varias instrucciones, imaginemos en pseudo código algo como:

```
  llamar a fibonacci(numero - 1)
  almacenar el resultado en una variable temporal1
  llamar a fibonacci(numero - 2)
  almacenar el resultado en una variable temporal2
  calcular el resultado de temporal1 + temporal2 en temporal3
  retornar el valor de temporal3
```

Estas variables temporales, que son locales, forman parte de cada *marco de pila*
cada llamada a `fibonacci()` tiene el potencial de generar otras llamadas, y cada una tendrá su propio *marco de pila* con el valor de las variables temporales de ESA llamada.

Al llegar finalmente a

```
return 1;
```

Se retorna dicho valor a la última llamada, y a partir de allí se va *desenrollando* la pila, haciendo las asignaciones correspondientes en el contexto de cada marco, hasta que se retorna de la primera llamada a `fibonacci()` con el resultado total del cálculo.